# Can I enter the UK as a tourist/in transit even having a valid student visa?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, brazilian-citizens, change-purpose-of-travel

I own a Brazilian passport. I will arrive in London, fly to France on the same day and spend 14 days there before going back to the UK for my studies. I will already have my student visa but I don't want to use it because I'll be required to register at the police within 7 days of entering the UK with it (when I'll be in France).
Can I first enter as a tourist or in transit and only on my second entry use my student visa?

Comment: Do you have another visa?

Comment: No, before arrival I'll only have a student visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brazilian citizens don't need a visa for the UK. You can check this on [UK Border Agency website](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/do-you-need-a-visa/). In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Brazilian_citizens) there is also a page that confirm that. So it should be no problem to enter UK without using your student visa.